# Use css to span width of screen

Tags: css, html

*style.css*

```
.headerBar table,tr,td{
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 44px;
    border: 0px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px; 
}
```

*video.html*

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="headerBar">
                <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                     FILL
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Question 1:**
<strike>I would like the table to span the width of the page, it won't</strike>. **solved**

**Question 2:**
<strike>I would like the table to sit at the very top of the page, so there are no borders or white space above, to the left, or to the right of the table.</strike> **solved**

**Question 3:**
Is there a better way of doing this? Possibly using something new to HTML5?

Thanks!

Comment: Change width: 100%px;   to width: 100%;

Comment: @sparkalow Yea I realized that right as I posted. Thanks though.

Comment: Avoid the use of tables for positioning/styling purposes, you can create all sorts of layouts with just divs or lists

Comment: @Kryptos, was that just a typo in the post or in your code as well?

Comment: @evan.stoddard It was a typo in my code >.>

Comment: @Kryptos Haha well glad that's all worked out.  A wise person on stack once told me, `It's easier to find fault's in someone else's code than in your own.`

Comment: @evan.stoddard I swear I stared at that for a good 5 min and couldn't find out what was wrong. lol. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it sit at the top with no borders, padding or width do something like this:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ESdDD/)

```
<div class="headerBar">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>FILL</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

.headerBar table, tr, td {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 44px;
    border: 0px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    position:fixed; /** or absolute, depending on what you are trying to accomplish **/
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

And yes, you should not be using tables for styling or layouts. You can accomplish the same with just `divs`

```
<div class="headerBar">
    FILL
</div>
```

/**** EDIT  ****/

To answer your third question, yes there are far better ways to do this... it doesn't necessarily involve HTML5, but just good HTML practice. If the project is big enough (and sometimes even if it isn't) you could and probably should use something like [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) which is a front-end framework that could possibly be of great benefit to you by including design concepts and examples to get you started.

Comment: I use a table because there will be more stuff in the bar. Essentially, I am cloning the top bar on each youtube page. Won't I need a table for position the items? Or can that be done with div as well?

Comment: No you do not need a `table` for positioning which is considered bad practice. You can `position` with `div`'s very easily with css.

Comment: Do you have any examples/links possibly?

Comment: Read [this](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/developing_with_web_standards/csslayout/2-col/) or [this](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/08/from-table-hell-to-div-hell/) which ties it all together. [THIS](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/horizontal01.htm) is how you can recreate a horizontal list.

Answer (score 1):

you have `width: 100%px;` it should be  `width: 100%;`

Answer (score 1):

First off I would recommend using a `div` instead of a `table` for many reasons but that is just me.

A `div` allows you to do way more than a `table` will and it is far less confusing when you have to edit it months down the road.

HTML Page

```
<header>
    <p> My text here </p>
</header>
<div class="widthS">
    <p> Whatever you are trying to put here </p>
</div>
<footer>
    <p> Copyright </p>
</footer>
```

CSS Page

```
.widthS {
background: #f1f1f1;
width: 100%;
height: 44px;
border: 0px;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}
```

Now you can add some really fun css features such as `box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #2b2b2b;` or `border-radius: 7px 7px 0 0;` or `opacity: 0.5;`. The first one adds an *almost* 90 degree angle drop shadow to an element, adds curved edges on the top corners, and this allows an element to be transparent.

Answer (score 0):

You said you still need2 and 3 answered, try this:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

It should have no borders now

Answer (score 0):

To your third question: It depends on what you want to do with the table... if you just use it to give your elements the right position, you should use div-elements and css instead. ;)

Answer (score 0):

you just need this for the first question:

```
.headerBar table{
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 44px;
    border: 0;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

There will not be anyspace around the table if you do not add any element before.

And about the third question. If it gets little bit more complex that that i advice you to do two things.

Follow a screencast about html and css or read a good book there are many out there just google it ... and on top of that when you are little bit more familiar with those two languages start to use a framework like Bootstrap or Foundation from Zurb and do not forget to look their source code.